# multiprocess package -> BaseProcess: `TypeError: BaseProcess._Popen()`

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess, dill

I am a noob in Python multiprocessing and trying to learn it.

While trying to run a class method on a separate Multiprocessing-Process. The Python class is initialized in the main process and I am trying to start a class method in a separate process.

```
def __initialise_strat_class_obj(self, *, strat_name: str, strat_config: StratInput): 
    try:
        strat_instance = strat_class_dict[strat_name](strat_args=self.strat_args, strat_input=strat_config)  # dynamically fetching & calling the class
        strat_instance.init()
    except Exception as e:
        self._logger.error(f"unable to init strategy `{strat_config.id}`: {e}")
        return False 
    strat_process = Process(target=strat_instance.run)
    strat_process.start()# starting the class method in a separate process
```

```
def start(self):
    self.init()
    if self.is_active():
        self.run()
    else:
        self._logger.warning(f"{self.id} -> strat is inactive, returning from thread")
    return
```

However, I encountered the `cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object` error. Below is the stack trace of the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\repo\StockTradeBotV2\src\strategy\__init__.py", line 237, in __init__
    self.__initialise_strat_class_obj(strat_name=strat_name, strat_config=strat_inp)
  File "D:\repo\StockTradeBotV2\src\strategy\__init__.py", line 263, in __initialise_strat_class_obj
    strat_process.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 94, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

To overcome the serialization issue, I made use of the `multiprocess` package which utilizes dill for serializing objects. This time I got a completely different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\repo\StockTradeBotV2\src\strategy\__init__.py", line 237, in __init__
    self.__initialise_strat_class_obj(strat_name=strat_name, strat_config=strat_inp)
  File "D:\repo\StockTradeBotV2\src\strategy\__init__.py", line 263, in __initialise_strat_class_obj
    strat_process.start()
  File "C:\PythonEnvironments\StockTradeBotV2\Lib\site-packages\multiprocess\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: BaseProcess._Popen() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I have tried calling the raw class without initializing and passing the self-argument which didn’t help. On changing the `Process` to `Thread`, the code works as intended without any errors, but I want this to run on its own process instead of parallelism so that the additional cores on my PC are used.

I am doing all this on `Python-3.11.1` with `multiprocess-0.70.14` package.

**Edit:** I have to use `multiprocess.Process` rather than `from multiprocess.process import BaseProcess as Process` which solved the issue

Comment: I'm the `multiprocess` author.  You are using `0.70.14` with python `3.11`.  Does your code work as expected in python `3.10`?  Python `3.11` is not supported in `0.70.14`, however it is supported in Github master. You also might want to try to pip install from Github master.  I will be cutting a new release (supporting `3.11`) in a few days.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I was using `from multiprocess.process import BaseProcess as Process` instead of `multiprocess.Process` and it worked fine without errors. I apologize for the inconvenience on my part. P.S., thanks for the awesome packages, you are a god!

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you have it sorted.